# CSS : Fullscreen in chrome-android doesn't respect viewport meta

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive, meta-tags

I'm a developping a web single page app (SPA)

In my header, i use the following viewport meta :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200, user-scalable=no">
```

I use that because this is for a landscape app, not responsive, which should render  approximately the same way on mobile than it does on desktop. 1200px is the dimension of the PSD.

Here is a simplified example of my problem.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class='test'></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{
    width:100%; height:100%;
}
.test{
    position:absolute;
    right:202px; top:39px;
    width:82px; height:99px;
    background-image:url('/assets/images/bg/bg2-moon.png'); 
    background-color:red;
}
```

On chrome / android, this render with the same proportion than on desktop, see screenshot below :

[image]

But when i switch in fullscreen mode, using :

```
document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen();
```

i loose the proportions i had, and my px measurement appears bigger.
[image]

The testing device is a Nexus 5 which has a DPR of 2 or 3 (i'm not sure), and i'm aware that this has to do with the rescaling of my px measurement.

I would like the fullscreen mode to render as the non fullscreen mode.
This is a simplified sample of a problem which appears on a full developed app, which use px extensively, so i would like if possible, not to change all my CSS to replace px with % or something like that.